# Is it possible to link my Careers 2.0 account, Stack Overflow, and Programmers Stack accounts together?

Tags: support

I believe that my SO and Programmers accounts are already as linked as they get, but the Careers one is a different thing entirely, it seems.

Comment: Are you using the same OpenID provider on Careers 2.0?

Comment: When I set up the Careers account I asked them if I could link with my existing SO account.  They said no, to create a new one, then link them after. So, that's where I'm at.  I am using a different ID since I used Google as my provider for SO and Programmers.

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately, you can have 2 OpenIDs associated with your Careers account, and [*any number of them*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/we-now-support-multiple-openids/) associated with your Stack Exchange account.

So if you're using two different IDs in two different places right now, just add them both (to your account here for sure, but slapping them both on Careers won't hurt either).